# Spacing between every 3 characters

Tags: android, android-edittext, mask, textwatcher

I'm stuck on how to make it so that i can space characters such as, 1 000, 10 000, 100 000, 10 000 000. As long as there is more than three characters, i need it to space the last three digits from the rest. If there are more than 6 characters, i need it to space two times, in the middle of the three last digits and before. I need this to be a mask for edittext so it formats it while being input. I was considering textwatcher, but was thinking if there was a better way to do it with regex. As a bonus, if there was a way to prefix '$' (dollar sign), that would be helpful aswell, but not necessary.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: Got it working with this:

```
StringBuilder ss;
        ss = new StringBuilder(text);

        for(int i = ss.length(); i > 0; i -= 3){
            ss.insert(i, " ");
        }

        return ss.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin:

This function will convert any text string without checking if it is a valid number or not, leaving a space every 3 characters and prefixing it with '$' (dollar sign)

```
private fun String.formatter(): String {
    val s = StringBuilder(this.reversed())
    s.forEachIndexed { index, _ ->
        if (index%4==0) s.insert(index," ")
    }
    return s.insert(s.lastIndex+1,"$").reversed().toString()
}
```

now you can call the function like this

```
val myString = "23456784657678"
myString.formatter() // => $23 456 784 657 678
```

You should check if it is a real monetary value and keep in mind that it can have decimals: $23 456 784 657 678.546

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a `TextWatcher` to achieve your purpose.Here is a simple way you could achieve the spaces:

```
StringBuilder s;
s = new StringBuilder(yourTxtView.getText().toString());

for(int i = 3; i < s.length(); i += 4){
    s.insert(i, " ");
}

yourTxtView.setText(s.toString());
```

Comment: Didn't quite work as intended, but after a little bit of tweaking i've got it working. Thanks for setting me on the right track atleast :)